# Updated to Android Studio 3.1 does not focus compile errors anymore

Tags: android, android-studio

3.1 introduces build output window which you can clearly see the build steps. However, prior to this 3.1 whenever the compiler runs and if there are errors it automatically focused on where the error is in the code. 3.1 does not do that it anymore. I wonder if there is an option there to turn on or I miss out something?

Answer (score 2):

It can be still done by double clicking on the error:
[image]

Alternatively, you can click on `Toggle View` and get the link to class in as done in previous version.

Comment: It is not clear, even the build window it won't directly show you where is the error. Sometimes I run it and go to the toilet and come back, nothing show on the screen, I don't know what is going until I check the build window.